# Finding the acute angle between two arbitrary lines

Tags: graphics, regions, geometry

Given two arbitrary lines using primitives such as `Line[{p1, p2}]` in the plane, how can the acute angle between them be computed?

```
line1 = Line[{{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}}];
line2 = Line[{{x3, y3}, {x4, y4}}];
```

This seems like such a fundamental operation, surely there is a simple way to do this in Mathematica?

Comment: Take the difference of the endpoints of the two line segments, and then use `VectorAngle[]`.

Comment: Regarding your deleted answer: don't use `Abs[]`; just the plain differences should work.

Answer (score 4):

I will load a demo using `PlanarAngle`.

```
Clear[line1, line2, sol]
line1 = InfiniteLine@RandomReal[{0, 1}, {2, 2}];
line2 = InfiniteLine@RandomReal[{0, 1}, {2, 2}];
(*RegionQ/@{line1,line2};*)
sol = RegionIntersection[line1, line2][[-1]];
ang = Min[#, 
     180 - #] &@(PlanarAngle[{line1[[-1, -1]], sol, 
       line2[[-1, -1]]}] 180/π);
Graphics[{
  Red, Dashed, line1
  , Blue, Dashed, line2
  , AbsolutePointSize[6], Point@(line1[[-1]])
  , AbsolutePointSize[6], Point@(line2[[-1]])
  , Thick, Dashing[{}], Red, line1 /. InfiniteLine :> Line
  , Thick, Dashing[{}], Blue, line2 /. InfiniteLine :> Line
  , Black, Point@sol, Darker@Green, Thin, Circle[sol, 0.04]
  }
 , Frame -> True
 (*,AxesOrigin\[Rule]sol[[-1]]*)
 , PlotRange -> Transpose@{sol + 1, sol - 1}
 , PlotRangeClipping -> True
 , PlotLabel -> Text[Style[ToString@ang <> "°", 16]]
 ]
```

A sample output is attached:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

From J.M.'s comment:

```
lineLineAngle[Line[{X1_, X2_}], Line[{X3_, X4_}]] := VectorAngle[X1 - X2, X4 - X3]
```

example:

```
line1 = Line@RandomReal[{0, 1}, {2, 2}];
line2 = Line@RandomReal[{0, 1}, {2, 2}];

lineLineAngle[line1, line2]
```

[image]

Comment: You should accept your own answer as this is the correct way of doing this calculation. I was demonstrating the use of `PlanarAngle`. It can be used to calculate interior angles when polygon points are known, for instance.

Comment: @Syed, thanks I will